# Visual Studio UPDATE-EDMX feature: How it works

Tags: visual-studio, ide, schema, edmx

When you use the `update-edmx` feature of visual studio.

Your EDMX schema is merged against a database.

### What Rules Apply to changes merging?

UPDATE: looks like **new** db fields are added to your edmx, **modified** fields are merged in someway and **deleted** ones are left in your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TheRules

*Added Notes*

If any objects have been added to the database (or were not included in the previous storage model), you can add them to the conceptual model -selecting them from the `add` tab in the update-edmx window.

*Updated Nodes*

Any changes that have been made to these database objects will be reflected in the updated storage model. Changes to the conceptual model are made when columns are added to a table or view.

*Deleted Nodes*

If an object has been deleted from the database and was included in the previous storage model. The objects in these nodes will be deleted from the updated model.

via [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716697%28VS.100%29.aspx)